# c# run method from abstract and inheritor with a single instance

Tags: c#, oop, methods, coding-style, abstract-class

Is there a way I could run my method from an abstract class without explicitly running it(I mean I have the same method name which would inherit it and what I want is to run both the one from the abstract and the one who inherited their routines)? or any kind of method (virtual override or normal)
or if not can I use it without using base.checker()?

example

```
public abstract class absclass1{
    protected void Checker(){
        Console.WriteLine("from absclass1");
    }
}

public class sample1 : absclass1
{
    protected void Checker(){
        Console.WriteLine("from sample1");
    }
}
```

if i have a class to run like:

```
public class main{
    public void main(){
    sample1 runner = new sample1();
    runner.checker();
    }
}
```

I would like to have my output as:

```
from absclass1
from sample
```

I expect the two methods named checker from the abstract and the inheritor to run or I really need to put base.checker(); at the checker at the inheritor? Thanks, sorry if you think what I'm trying is weird or easy. And if possible please site some bestpractices you know that would be useful for me.

ps
feel free to edit if you think something's wrong with my question

Answer (score 4):

you can call **base** (absclass1) from your **sample1** class:

```
public class sample1 : absclass1
{
protected void Checker(){

  base.Checker()
  console.writeln("from sample1");
 
}
```

}

So when you execute:

```
public class main{
    public void main(){
    sample1 runner = new sample1();
    runner.checker();
    }
}
```

Your output will be:

> from absclass1
>
> from sample

Comment: so there is no way to run both without adding base.checker()?

Comment: No, but that's a Good Thing™, because it creates more readability.

Comment: If you inherit an abstract class, the correct way to call the function you are implemeting is using base.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it without calling `base.Checker`. The only time when a method is automatically called is in a constructor. Your code should thus call `base.Checker` to get the desired result:

```
public abstract class absclass1
{
    protected void Checker() {
        Console.WriteLine("from absclass1");
    }
}

public class sample1 : absclass1
{
    protected void Checker() {
        Console.WriteLine("from sample1");
        base.Checker();
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
from sample1
from absclass1
```

Just to show you constructors do work as you wanted the method to work:

```
public abstract class absclass1
{
    protected absclass1() {
        console.writeln("from absclass1");
    }
}

public class sample1 : absclass1
{
    public sample1 () {
        console.writeln("from sample1");
    }
}
```

This will also output:

```
from sample1
from absclass1
```

The only difference being that the constructor call is of course only called once, whereas the regular method can be called whenever you want.

Comment: since you mention a constructor, is it possible for me to modify a method in the constructor? like i would like to merge the existing at the class and the one from the abstract so i can get my desired result?

Comment: @sclang What do you mean exactly by modifying the constructor? You can call methods from your constructor, so in essence you can combine method 1 with method 2 by calling the methods from the constructors.

Comment: i mean i will modify method 1, making it like method1=method1+method2, during the constructor phase, hahaha, anyway thanks for the opinion i just thought adding the base.checker() at checker() is a bad practice :)

Comment: @sclang Ah I see. Using `base.Checker()` is perfectly fine, you should be using that. Good luck!